# Swagger UI: How to custom sort resources

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

Quiet pretty straighforward question: how can I sort the endpoints in swagger-ui in v2.2.6? I'm using springfox for the java part.

In my main page of swagger, I'm having a collection of resources grouped by tags. These tags are in a random order. I would like to have it in a custom order (and if it's not possible, alphabetically).
My SwaggerConfig.java file:

```
package cat.meteo.apiinterna.commons.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.service.Tag;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .tags(
                    new Tag("XEMA Me", "1"),
                    new Tag("XEMA Ul", "2"),
                    new Tag("XEMA Ag", "3"),
                    new Tag("Prono", "4"),
                    new Tag("Sound", "5")
            )
            .apiInfo(apiInfo());
}

private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
    return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("API REST")
            .description("Self-documented API")
            .version("v0.1.0")
            .build();
    }
}
```

And this is the tag resulting json file that swagger-ui uses in the same order. As you can see the order seems to be random. Not the java tags order, not alphabetically.
(http://localhost:8080/XXX/v2/api-docs)

```
"tags": [
{
"name": "XEMA Ul",
"description": "2"
},
{
"name": "XEMA Me",
"description": "1"
},
{
"name": "XEMA Ag",
"description": "3"
},
{
"name": "Sound",
"description": "5"
},
{
"name": "Prono",
"description": "4"
}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging into the problem, I see that new versions of swagger-ui do not support custom ordering as an option. Springfox also give no chance of reorder the generated json, so the only way is to implement a "workaround" in swagger-ui.

In render function, line 21766 of swagger-ui.js file (v2.2.6):

```
// Workaround: alphabetically ordered tags
this.api.apisArray.sort(function (a, b) {
if (a.tag < b.tag)
    return -1;
if (a.tag > b.tag)
    return 1;
return 0;
})
```

With this code the UI shows the tags ordered.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve something similar using the Quarkus-based rest application? I tried to achieve something similar for my quarkus-based application but could not get anything. Please find my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74627820/7584240

Answer (score 3):

Alphabetical order seems to be the default. However I needed a custom order of my tags.

I had this problem today but due to a strike of luck I found out the tag ctor takes a int order.
It seems to work for me!

So, re-using your code sample:

```
...
            .tags(
                    new Tag("foo", "tag description", 2),
                    new Tag("bar", "another desc   ", 1),
...
```

And tag `foo` appears after tag `bar` on swagger UI.

(I'm using springfox v2.9.2)

Comment: Is there a way to achieve something similar using the Quarkus-based rest application? I tried to achieve something similar for my quarkus-based application but could not get anything. Please find my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74627820/7584240