# Java Quarkus OpenAPI: How to order various paths in a Quarkus resource?

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, quarkus

How can I add the sorting order for my API path endpoints using the Java OpenAPI annotations? I am currently using `Quarkus` to develop a rest-based application within that I am using the OpenAPI annotations to generate the Swagger-UI but I am not able to control the orders for various paths that appear. Is there a way to achieve this by forcing the OpenAPI to always sort as per my need?

Following are multiple resources and endpoints I have:

ExtensionsResource:

```
@Path("/api")
@Tag(
    name = "Extensions Controller",
    description = "Extensions Information")
public class ExtensionResource {

    @POST
    @Path("/post/extensions")
    public String list() {
        return extension;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/get/extension")
    public String list() {
        return extension;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/post/extension")
    public String list() {
        return extension;
    }
}
```

I always want to ensure that the swagger-ui displays the API endpoints in the following order:

```
1. api/get/extension
2. api/post/extension
3. api/post/extensions
```

This above code is just for reference my actual code looks different I just want to know how to force the ordering of endpoints in Swagger-UI using the OpenAPI annotation.

**Updated**
The contents of my `application.yaml` file looks something like this:

```
quarkus:
  swagger-ui:
    always-include: true
    tagsSorter: "alpha"
    operationsSorter: "alpha"
  http:
    cors: true
    port: 9000
```

Comment: Is this the same question as [your previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74614616/113116)?

Comment: @Helen Thanks a lot for the response. It's a bit the same but not completely. There I was also trying to order between multiple tags which I was able to accomplish finally. Now, within a single tag, I would like to order my various endpoints so its kind of part of that question but not complete. I will add the answer to that and close it to avoid any confusion. Is there any workaround for this question?

Comment: Swagger UI has the [`operationSorter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69296074/113116) option to control the sorting. Quarkus analog seems to be [`quarkus.swagger-ui.operations-sorter`](https://quarkus.io/guides/openapi-swaggerui#quarkus-swaggerui_quarkus.swagger-ui.operations-sorter). You should be able to specify a custom sort function as [shown here](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/15642).

Comment: @Helen Thanks a lot for the response and links. I am trying to follow it but facing some issues and am unable to make it work. I tried adding the lines `tagsSorter: "alpha"` and `operationsSorter: "alpha"` to my `application.yml` file. I believe I need only the `operationsSorter`. Can you please provide some examples or references based on the above-provided example? That will be really helpful for me. I have added the contents of my `application.yml` file in the above question for your reference.

Comment: [Quarkus doc](https://quarkus.io/guides/openapi-swaggerui#quarkus-swaggerui_quarkus.swagger-ui.operations-sorter) says the config name is `operations-sorter`, not `operationsSorter` like in the standalone Swagger UI. Other than that I don't know what might be wrong as I never used Quarkus myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working by adding the functions in my `public class SchemaExampleOASFilter implements OASFilter`. I added the `operationsId` to my routes something like this:

```
@Path("/api")
@Tag(
    name = "Extensions Controller",
    description = "Extensions Information")
public class ExtensionResource {

    @Operation(operationId = "3")
    @POST
    @Path("/post/extensions")
    public String list() {
        return extension;
    }

    @Operation(operationId = "1")
    @GET
    @Path("/get/extension")
    public String list() {
        return extension;
    }
    
    @Operation(operationId = "2")
    @POST
    @Path("/post/extension")
    public String list() {
        return extension;
    }
}
```

Added the `SchemaExampleOASFilter` something like this:

```
public class SchemaExampleOASFilter implements OASFilter {

    @Override
    public void filterOpenAPI(OpenAPI openAPI) {

        //Method to sort various operations based on operationID to display in Swagger-UI
        final Map < String, PathItem > pathItems = openAPI.getPaths().getPathItems().entrySet().stream().sorted((o1, o2) - > {
            if (o1.getValue().getPOST() != null && o2.getValue().getPOST() != null) {
                int v1 = Integer.parseInt(o1.getValue().getPOST().getOperationId());
                int v2 = Integer.parseInt(o2.getValue().getPOST().getOperationId());
                return Integer.compare(v1, v2);
            }
            return 0;
        }).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (v1, v2) - > v1, LinkedHashMap::new));

        //Add the sorted operations to Swagger-UI
        openAPI.getPaths().setPathItems(pathItems);

    }
}
```

And added it to my `application.yml` file something like this:

```
quarkus:
  swagger-ui:
    always-include: true
  http:
    cors: true
    port: 9000

mp:
  openapi:
    filter: "com.example.my.package.SchemaExampleOASFilter"
```

This made everything work for me and now, I am able to sort however I want.